# Add created class file to project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a console application that builds some default classes for me from a database. When the files are built, I want to be able to refresh my folders and see the new files in my class library.

However no matter what I do the files don't show up unless I go in and manually add existing files.  Is there a way for VS2010 to look at the file folder and add in anything that is in that folder to the project?  For example:

> Folder > File1.cs, File2.cs, File3.cs, File4.cs

VS2010 sees

> Folder > File1.cs

How can I make VS2010 show these new classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you will only see files that are included and referenced in your .csproj file. This is by and large a good thing because it gives you ultimate control over what is taken into account in the project or not. This is causing you a problem though, because the created files which are inserted into your project directory aren't being referenced. As you have mentioned you can include the files manually, but I understand that you wish this process to be automatic.

The best way to resovle this in my opinion is instead of having a project create the files, use **design-time T4 templates**. Design-time T4 templates are files which resemble pre-Razor ASP.NET views, which allow code generation within your project. You can access your database, format your classes and then output .cs files directly into your project without building it. This is extremely convenient becuase it lets you work on catching compile-time errors that may come up based on the output without having to do a complete build.

[More information about using T4 can be found here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx)

[And a good walkthrough can be found here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd820614.aspx)

Comment: this doesn't resolve the problem because I may create a whole new database and then run this application on it and create "N" number of classes from it.  So I can create 50, 100, 1000 classes depending on my database in a 30 second to 1 minute run.

Comment: while my last comment is a bit extreme with 1000 classes it would be possible and doing each manually is what I am doing already.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how T4 is in conflict with creating your classes, but anyways if it really isn't an option you may be able to edit your csproj file with your program if you run it without debugging. I am just guessing here but I imagine that it would have the same effect as editing the csproj with notepad while running the generated executable. You could look into thus modifying the csproj to include your generated files once they have been created. I still think T4 (or even a NuGet package) is a better bet if you can make it work, though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the project where you can find your file
2. On top of your solution explorer you can select "show all files"
3. Select your files and include

Adding them automatically can be done from another app or script by modifying your projects .csproj/vbproj file

```
    <Compile Include="My Project\MyClass.vb" />
```

This must be done in the correct itemgroup.

Comment: this would still be a manual action, correct? Can it be done automatically?

Comment: if you are running the application it is not possible, you will have to edit your vbProj file and add: <Compile Include="My Project\MyFile1.vb" /> in the correct itemgroup

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this personally, but you should be able to do it using this..

First gain a reference to your project using your apps' solution, then with the Visual Studio automation framework (DTE):

```
ProjectItems p = Project.ProjectItems;
p.AddFromFile("File1.cs");
```

Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile.aspx
I would read further into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not directly possible. You may write a [template file (t4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd820620.aspx) in order to create you cs files and they will be added to project when the transformation file is run.

In order to run the transformation file after / before build, you may write a pre/post build event.

Answer (score 0):

That will require you to create a VS add-in.. you can find an example [here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228774.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> Okay so I have a console application that is building some default classes for me from a database.

Can't you let this application write all classes in one file, say `Proxy.cs` or `Entities.cs`. Then every time you regenerate the file and rebuild the project, you can access the new classes.

Comment: yeah once the file is added that's fine but the issue is that I may be adding 50 new classes that have not been added before and rather than go through and include each one manually I want VS to pick it up on the fly

Comment: @CBRRacer I said: generate all classes in one file. Or perhaps make it even generate a solution and classes, so you can reference the solution.

Comment: that would work but that's not the solution that I am looking for.  I want each class to be in it's own class file.